# How can I make an invoice from custom module ?? I know I need to make Create method for invoice but where to put that method ?? I am beginner in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

This is my Custom Module :
[image]

When I Click on Create invoice button it shows wizard as shown below :
[image]

But when I try to Create regular invoice it shows error :

[image]

I Changed the invoicing policy of product from "delivered quantities" to "ordered quantities" but still it throws same error.

xml code adding buttons :

```
          <header>
                <button name="action_draft" string="Draft" type="object" data-hotkey="r"/>
                <button name="action_in_progress" string="In Progress" type="object" data-hotkey="p"/>
                <button name="action_done" string="Done" type="object" states="in_progress"/>
                <button name="action_cancel" string="Cancel" type="object" data-hotkey="x"/>
                <field name="state" widget="statusbar" nolabel="1"/>
                <button name="331" string="Create Invoice" type="action" data-hotkey="x" states="done"/>
            </header>
```

Comment: Pl add your code. What does your Create Invoice button do ?

Comment: @NinjaBat   I have added the xml code in question and yes I simply added name of button as 331 because I have seen the same in sale order module. So to create invoice from my job card I did the same.

Comment: You can't do that way. It will try to take value from sale.order because that's how the button function is. 
1. Create your own button. 2. Pass necessary values(partner_id,product_id,..) and call create() function for 'account.move'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a python function that does it and then to call that function by naming a button as your function.

[Odoo tutorial explaining how to proceed](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/14_other_module.html)

[Code example about how to create an account.move](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/353b0a436ec9d194699bed1ba1cbf95b97e4a29b/addons/sale/tests/test_reinvoice.py#L123-L144)

Don't forget to add taxes if you need to.